# Testing coroutine with delay

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines, delay

I have a method called `fetchHabits()` that calls an Use Case that fetches some data for me. In my implementation, if this usecase returns an error on a first call, I have to call it again after a 500ms delay and on a second call, it may return a success. If it does return a success, I update the data on my savedStateHandle with the data I got from the Use Case. This is exactly the scenario I want to test. Call the `fetchHabits()` method. mock my Use Case to return an error at first and then a success and see if the data was set on my `savedStateHandle`.

This is my ViewModel, where the `fetchHabits()` method is implemented:

```kotlin
abstract class HabitListViewModel<T : PeriodicHabit>(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val getCurrentDailyHabitsUseCase: GetCurrentHabitsUseCase<T>,
    private val finishDailyHabitUseCase: FinishHabitUseCase<T>,
    private val dispatcherHandler: DispatcherHandler,
) : ViewModel() {

    @Suppress("PropertyName")
    abstract val HABITS_KEY: String

    @Suppress("LeakingThis")
    val habits: StateFlow<PeriodicHabitResult<T>> = savedStateHandle.getStateFlow(
        HABITS_KEY, PeriodicHabitResult.Loading
    )

    @VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)
    var isFirstFetch = true

    fun fetchHabits(): Job = viewModelScope.launch(dispatcherHandler.IO) {
        setPeriodicHabitResult(PeriodicHabitResult.Loading)
        val result = getCurrentDailyHabitsUseCase()
        if (result is Result.Error) {
            if (isFirstFetch) {
                isFirstFetch = false
                delay(500)
                val secondResult = getCurrentDailyHabitsUseCase()
                if (secondResult is Result.Error) {
                    setPeriodicHabitResult(PeriodicHabitResult.Error)
                } else {
                    if (result.value?.isEmpty() != false) {
                        setPeriodicHabitResult(PeriodicHabitResult.EmptyList)
                    } else {
                        setPeriodicHabitResult(PeriodicHabitResult.Success(result.value))
                    }
                }
                fetchHabits()
            } else {
                setPeriodicHabitResult(PeriodicHabitResult.Error)
            }
        } else {
            if (result.value?.isEmpty() != false) {
                setPeriodicHabitResult(PeriodicHabitResult.EmptyList)
            } else {
                setPeriodicHabitResult(PeriodicHabitResult.Success(result.value))
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setPeriodicHabitResult(periodicHabitResult: PeriodicHabitResult<T>) {
        savedStateHandle[HABITS_KEY] = periodicHabitResult
    }
```

This is the class I want to test, which extends the HabitListViewModel class:

```
class WeeklyHabitListViewModel(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    getCurrentHabitsUseCase: GetCurrentHabitsUseCase<WeeklyHabit>,
    finishHabitUseCase: FinishHabitUseCase<WeeklyHabit>,
    dispatcherHandler: DispatcherHandler,
) : HabitListViewModel<WeeklyHabit>(
    savedStateHandle,
    getCurrentHabitsUseCase,
    finishHabitUseCase,
    dispatcherHandler
) {

    override val HABITS_KEY: String
        get() = "WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY"
}
```

The `DispatcherHandler` is an interface I use to handle Dispatchers:

```kotlin
@Suppress("PropertyName")
interface DispatcherHandler {

    val Default: CoroutineDispatcher

    val IO: CoroutineDispatcher

    val Main: CoroutineDispatcher

    val Unconfined: CoroutineDispatcher
}
```

In my production code, this is the implementation I use:

```kotlin
object DispatcherHandlerImpl : DispatcherHandler {
    override val Default: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.Default

    override val IO: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.IO

    override val Main: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.Main

    override val Unconfined: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.Unconfined
}
```

This is the implementation of my Use Case:

```kotlin
class GetCurrentHabitsUseCase<T : PeriodicHabit>(
    private val periodicHabitRepository: PeriodicHabitRepository<T>,
) {

    suspend operator fun invoke(): Result<List<T>> = resultBy {
        periodicHabitRepository.getHabitsForLastPeriod()
    }
}
```

In this test, this is what I'm using:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
object DispatcherHandlerUnconfined : DispatcherHandler {

    override val Default: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()

    override val IO: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()

    override val Main: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()

    override val Unconfined: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
}
```

So far, my test class is like this:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class WeeklyHabitsViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    val coroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule()

    @RelaxedMockK
    private lateinit var savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle

    @RelaxedMockK
    private lateinit var getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase: GetCurrentHabitsUseCase<WeeklyHabit>

    @RelaxedMockK
    private lateinit var finishWeeklyHabitUseCase: FinishHabitUseCase<WeeklyHabit>

    private lateinit var viewModel: WeeklyHabitListViewModel

    companion object {
        private const val WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY: String = "WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY"
    }

    init {
        initMockKAnnotations()
        mockInitialValueForHabitResult()
        initializeViewModel()
    }

    private fun mockInitialValueForHabitResult() {
        every {
            savedStateHandle.getStateFlow(WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY, PeriodicHabitResult.Loading)
        } returns MutableStateFlow(PeriodicHabitResult.Loading)
    }

    private fun initializeViewModel() {
        viewModel = spyk(
            WeeklyHabitListViewModel(
                savedStateHandle,
                getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase,
                finishWeeklyHabitUseCase,
                DispatcherHandlerUnconfined
            )
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun `GIVEN getCurrentWeeklyHabits returns an error once and then a success on the second attempt WHEN fetchHabits called THEN must set PeriodicHabitResult_Success`() =
        runTest {
            val throwable = Throwable()
            val expectedList = listOf(FIRST_WEEKLY_HABIT, SECOND_WEEKLY_HABIT)
            coEvery { getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase() } returns throwable.toError() andThen expectedList.toSuccess()
            viewModel.isFirstFetch = true

            Assert.assertEquals(PeriodicHabitResult.Loading, viewModel.habits.value)

            viewModel.fetchHabits()

            advanceTimeBy(500)

            coVerifyOrder {
                savedStateHandle[WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY] = PeriodicHabitResult.Loading
                getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase()
                getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase()
                savedStateHandle[WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY] = PeriodicHabitResult.Success(expectedList)
            }
        }
}
```

However, this is not working, and the error says it is only calling my usecase once:

```
Verification failed: fewer calls happened than demanded by order verification sequence. 

Matchers: 
+SavedStateHandle(savedStateHandle#3).set(eq(WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY), eq(com.hikarisource.smarthabits.presentation.features.list.viewmodel.PeriodicHabitResult$Loading@2f4ba1ae)))
+GetCurrentHabitsUseCase(getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase#2).invoke(any()))
+GetCurrentHabitsUseCase(getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase#2).invoke(any()))
SavedStateHandle(savedStateHandle#3).set(eq(WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY), eq(Success(data=[WeeklyHabit(id=1, description=Description one, completed=true, period=1), WeeklyHabit(id=2, description=Description two, completed=false, period=2)]))))

Calls:
1) SavedStateHandle(savedStateHandle#3).getStateFlow(WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY, com.hikarisource.smarthabits.presentation.features.list.viewmodel.PeriodicHabitResult$Loading@2f4ba1ae)
2) +SavedStateHandle(savedStateHandle#3).set(WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY, com.hikarisource.smarthabits.presentation.features.list.viewmodel.PeriodicHabitResult$Loading@2f4ba1ae)
3) +GetCurrentHabitsUseCase(getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase#2).invoke(continuation {})
```

##### What I have tried so far:

1. Change the `advanceTimeBy(500)` to `advanceUntilIdle()`.
2. Change the `advanceTimeBy(500)` to `delay(500)`.
3. Removing the `advanceTimeBy(500)` because I was sure the runTest would skip all the delays automaticly.
4. Change the `runTest {` to `runTest(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) {`
5. Removing the `advanceTimeBy(500)` and calling the join method on the job returned by the fetchHabits() like this: `viewModel.fetchHabits().join()`, but it made my test fail waiting more than 60000ms.

I know I'm still new to Coroutines, so this might not be a big problem, but I can't figure out what is the problem :\

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by passing the same UnconfinedTestDispatcher I'm injecting on my viewmodel to the runTest method and using the `advanceUntilIdle()` method on my test. To do it, I first created a DispatcherHandler implementation where I can pass the dispatcher I want so I can keep a reference on my test:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class DispatcherHandlerCustom(
    override val Default: CoroutineDispatcher,
    override val IO: CoroutineDispatcher,
    override val Main: CoroutineDispatcher,
    override val Unconfined: CoroutineDispatcher,
) : DispatcherHandler {

    constructor(coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) : this(
        coroutineDispatcher,
        coroutineDispatcher,
        coroutineDispatcher,
        coroutineDispatcher
    )
}
```

Then I crearted a field for an `UnconfinedTestDispatcher()` on my test class:

```kotlin
private val unconfinedTestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
```

And initialized my viewmodel passing this reference to the `DispatcherHandlerCustom`:

```kotlin
private fun initializeViewModel() {
    viewModel = spyk(
        WeeklyHabitListViewModel(
            savedStateHandle,
            getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase,
            finishWeeklyHabitUseCase,
            DispatcherHandlerCustom(unconfinedTestDispatcher)
        )
    )
}
```

Then, on my test cases, I just passed my `unconfinedTestDispatcher` reference to my `runTest` and called the `advanceUntilIdle()` to skip the delay:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `GIVEN getCurrentWeeklyHabits returns an error once and then a success on the second attempt WHEN fetchHabits called THEN must set PeriodicHabitResult_Success`() = runTest(unconfinedTestDispatcher) {
    val expectedList = listOf(FIRST_WEEKLY_HABIT, SECOND_WEEKLY_HABIT)
    coEvery { getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase() } returns Throwable().toError() andThen expectedList.toSuccess()
    viewModel.isFirstFetch = true

    Assert.assertEquals(PeriodicHabitResult.Loading, viewModel.habits.value)

    viewModel.fetchHabits()

    advanceUntilIdle()

    coVerifyOrder {
        savedStateHandle[WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY] = PeriodicHabitResult.Loading
        getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase()
        getCurrentWeeklyHabitsUseCase()
        savedStateHandle[WEEKLY_HABITS_KEY] = PeriodicHabitResult.Success(expectedList)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting, after advancing time, that the code in your coroutine to *instantaneously, in parallel* execute. This is not a reasonable expectation, as the [advanceByTime](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-delay-controller/advance-time-by.html) API doesn't specify that it will immediately and fully yield to all waiting coroutines before returning control.

Also, even though your update thread is launched on the IO dispatcher, you're not guaranteed perfect parallelism either, and your verification call is literally nanoseconds after advancing time.

If you call `delay(0)` from your test routine after advancing time, that might be enough to yield control long enough for your update to take place (read about the semantics of delay 0 elsewhere). Or, even `delay(5)` to give yourself extra room for the dispatchers do to their thing.

Comment: But how will the code look like with this delay? Where should I put it?

Comment: @LeonardodeOliveiraSibela `advanceUntilIdle` works perfectly as you did: the contract specifies exactly what you want: *Immediately execute all pending tasks and advance the virtual clock-time to the last delay* - which is effectively a yield and flush. This is better than a `delay` (after advancing the time).